# How to programmatically generate JSF components at run time?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I've got to create screens to display a lot of JPA entities in the View. It would be great to create one facelet and pass to it a collection of fields e.g. `List<Object>`.

The facelet/custom component would need to convert each element of the list into the appropriate tag for display e.g. an enum field to h:selectOneMenu, String field to h:inputText, etc.  This would need to be done at run time.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Worked on a project previously that created entire pages dynamically from stored configuration.  There are two basic things you need

- A BackingBean.  You'll used this to get access to the UIComponent on the facelet which will act as the parent to the generated UIComponents.  Something like a panelGroup.  But, you'll need to bind the UIComponent to the backing bean, in order to have a parent against which you'll add the dynamically-created UIComponents
- Access to the Application component.  Typically FacesContext.getApplication() (I worked on this in JavaEE 5, so it might look a little different with injection).  Once you have the Application component, you call the createComponent method, passing in the type of component you want to create.

It then becomes an activity of creating components dynamically, configuring them in code and adding them to the parent UIComponent defined via a binding bean.  It can be tricky, but it can be done.

Comment: Wow!  Cool!  On my project on the server side I used org.primefaces.component.toolbar.Toolbar and added UIComponent children to it. In the facelet I did `<p:toolBar binding="#{primeFacesMenuBuilder.toolbar}"/>` and voila it generated the entire toolbar at run time. In that case the toolbar was generated uniquely for each user, which was really sweet.  In the facelet one tag, p:toolbar, did it.  In the scenario that you describe what would it look like in the facelet e.g. what tag would I bind the root UIComponent to?

Comment: It would look very similar to what you describe, I think.  You'd probably use a h:panelGroup in the facelet itself, or something like that which will be the parent container UIComponent.  You bind it exactly the same as you described in the toolbar example, using the binding attribute.  The framework will create the UIComponent and you will have a reference to it in the backingBean.  Once you have that, you can add the child UIComponents to it, which are created programmatically.